# How to dismiss EditActionsForRow cell action menu on action tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I have a `UITableView`, the cells inside can be swiped for accessing some editing parameters.

The problem is the following: is there a way to programmatically dismiss the action panel (the one you get after swiping the cell)?

By action panel I mean the options popping after the swipe.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to call `[_tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];`

Comment: The question is tagged "swift", not "objective-c": please provide an answer in the language OP specified. Thanks!